# Hide return code from subprocess.call

Tags: python

How can I hide the return code after calling a command using subprocess?

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import subprocess

for ip in IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/19'):
        print subprocess.call(["host", str(ip)]
```

If I then pipe this to a file I get the host + ip but with a return code of 0 after each line.

Comment: Why did you put the `print` there?

Comment: I think they asked why you had `print` because *that* is the reason you are seeing the return code.  If you remove `print` the return code will not be shown.  If you were truely lazy, you wouldn't have typed `print`, and this problem wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Touche.  Thanks @Bakuriu, SethMMorton.  Works as expected now.

Comment: e.g. `subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])` suppresses the return code

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.call returns the return code, and you are seeing it because you are printing it. The other output is being printed to stdout from the host program, since it isn't being redirected from the subprocess.call method.

If you want to capture the output of the process you are calling you should take a look at Popen's communicate method

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to capture `stdout` and `stderr`.

```
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-alh', '/tmp/foo'],
...                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
...                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
...                          shell=False)
>>> 
>>> stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
>>> proc.returncode
0
```

Comment: Wait, the question isn't about how to capture standard output or standard error... it's about how to not show the return code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably super dead by now, but figured I'd add my two cents since I was just looking into this.

I thought the same way that I'd have to encapsulate in print. I was getting error standard out plus the 0 exit code (standard error) after each line as well.

When I removed it from the print statement, it removed the exit code (standard error) but still printed the standard output (the output of the command).

Try this:

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import subprocess

for ip in IPNetwork('1.1.1.1/19'):
    subprocess.call(["host", str(ip)])
```

I don't have the netaddr module installed so I can't tell you if it works or not.